# Transform a vector field

Tags: transformation, vector-fields

I was trying to transform a vector field in cartesian coordinates given by:

$$v_{cartesian}=(x^{2}+y^{2},y)$$

to polar coordinates. If I use the [transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331802/jacobian-matrix-vs-transformation-matrix) law for the components of a vector field

I get
$$v_{polar}=(r(r Cos \theta+sin^2 \theta),(-r+cos \theta) sin \theta)$$

However if  I use mathematica and the function **TransformedField** I get

```
TransformedField[ "Cartesian" -> "Polar", {x^2 + y^2, y}, {x, y} -> {r, \[Theta]}] // Simplify
```

$$v_{polar}=(r(r Cos \theta+sin^2 \theta),r(-r+cos \theta) sin \theta)$$

Which one is the right answer?

Comment: Are you sure that the basis vectors are the same for the two transformations? In particular, $\hat\theta$ isn’t always normalized.

Comment: I used the transformation law for the components of a tensor field of this book "General Relativity. Wald" (Equation 2.210.)

Comment: As I pointed out already, different sources use different basis vectors for the $\theta$ direction. It isn’t always a unit vector, so the components can differ by a factor of $1/r$,

Comment: Thank you @amd! That's what i needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\left(x^2+y^2\right) \mathbf{i}+y\, \mathbf{j}&=
r^2\left(\mathbf{u}_r\cos\theta-\mathbf{u}_\theta
\sin\theta\right) +r\sin\theta \left(\mathbf{u}_r\sin\theta+\mathbf{u}_\theta
\cos\theta\right)\\
&= r\left(r\cos\theta+\sin^2\theta\right)\mathbf{u}_r+ r\sin\theta\left(-r+\cos\theta\right)\mathbf{u}_\theta\ ,
\end{align}
which agrees with the result given by Mathematica.